# VBA - Deleting duplicate rows and merging cells with unique data

Tags: excel, vba, merge, duplicates, row

I have would like some help regarding the following problem. Every quarter we a have excel sheets sent to us with client info containing rows often more than a 1000. I've managed to write a code that deletes duplicate rows that are a 100% match, however, a considerable portion still remains due to the following:

[image]

A new code I have found kinda works, however I would need some help tweaking it, as it does the following:
[image]

It deletes the duplicate and merges the cells, however, if one cell value (in this case Marketing) appears both times it keeps it twice. Also, it does not retain other info like mail/name/phone etc.

Here's the code itself:

```
Sub Main()
Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim Destination As Worksheet: Set Destination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim Records As Object: Set Records = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim Data As Variant
Dim Index As Long
Dim Row As Integer: Row = 1

Data = Source.Range("A1", "E" & Source.Rows(Source.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row).Value2

For Index = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
If Records.Exists(Data(Index, 1)) Then
    Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2 = Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2 & ", " & Data(Index, 5)
Else
    Records.Add Data(Index, 1), Row
    Destination.Cells(Row, 1).Value2 = Data(Index, 1)
    Destination.Cells(Row, 5).Value2 = Data(Index, 5)
    Row = Row + 1
End If
Next Index

Set Records = Nothing

End Sub
```

I was wondering if there is a way to tackle this problem, or is it too complicated? If the latter, no problems, only deleting the duplicates works fine and reduces work hours a lot.

Thank you for any input and comment!

Comment: Create a Class where one member is `Name` and all the other information and the other is a Dictionary of `Units`.  Use the `.Exists` method to weed out the duplicate units.

Comment: @MaciejLos  What is your point?

Comment: @MaciejLos It is common in VBA.  From the VBE main menu bar, select `Insert` ► `Class Module`.  For further information about Classes in VBA, I refer you to Chip Pearson's [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a Dictionary to remove duplicates in a comma delimit string.  Email, code and Country are also copied over to the Destination worksheet.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Destination As Worksheet: Set Destination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim Records As Object: Set Records = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim Row As Integer: Row = 1

    Data = Source.Range("A1", "E" & Source.Rows(Source.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row).Value2
    With Destination

        For Index = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
            If Records.Exists(Data(Index, 1)) Then
                Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2 = removeDuplicates(Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2 & ", " & Data(Index, 5))
            Else
                Records.Add Data(Index, 1), Row
                Destination.Cells(Row, 1).Value2 = Data(Index, 1)
                Destination.Cells(Row, 2).Value2 = Data(Index, 2)
                Destination.Cells(Row, 3).Value2 = Data(Index, 3)
                Destination.Cells(Row, 4).Value2 = Data(Index, 4)
                Destination.Cells(Row, 5).Value2 = Data(Index, 5)
                Row = Row + 1
            End If
        Next Index

    End With
    Set Records = Nothing

End Sub

Function removeDuplicates(values As String)
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim d As Object
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each v In Split(values, ",")
        If v <> "" Then d(v) = 1
    Next

    removeDuplicates = Join(d.Keys, ", ")

    Set d = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
If Records.Exists(Data(Index, 1)) Then
    If InStr(Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2, Data(Index, 5)) = 0 Then 
        Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2 = Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2 & ", " & Data(Index, 5)
    End if
...
```

InStr searches for a certain String in another, and returns the position at which the string is found. Hence, if Marketing not found, instr will return 0 and it will be added to the cell. If it is already there, Instr will return something largern than 0 and it will not be added again.

**Update** If you have more records with more than one unit, try this

```
UnitFull = Data(Index, 5)

Do Until Len(UnitFull) = 0
    If InStr(UnitFull, ",") > 0 Then
        Unit = Left(UnitFull, Instr(UnitFull, ",") - 1)
        UnitFull = Trim(Right(UnitFull, Len(UnitFull) - InStr(UnitFull, ",")))

    Else

        Unit = UnitFull
        UnitFull = ""

    End If

    Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2 = Destination.Cells(Records(Data(Index, 1)), 5).Value2 & ", " & Unit

    Unit = ""

Loop
```

Comment: Hi!
I've tried to insert it (the first one) however it does not seem to change anything for me unfortunately. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Hi, just to check, you did delete the existing data, right? If so, try to set a breaktpoint or use debug.print in the line, to see what it does in more detail.